# Get element background color in EA

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

How can I get color of element (eg. boundary) by using official API?

I assume that it's save in database in t_objects -> backcolor, but I cannot find property/method in `Element` to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none. You need to use

```
repository.SQLQuery("SELECT Backcolor, Bordercolor, BoderWidth, Fontcolor FROM t_object WHERE ...")
```

> Coloring values in EA have simple RGB values without transparency. Each red, blue and green value can take an intensity from 0 to 255. The RGB itself is calculated by
>
> ```
>  RGB = (blue * 256 + green) * 256 + red
> ```
>
> The default coloring is equal to -1.

From my [Scripting EA](http://liquit.biz/brain/books.html) book.

Comment: Can you just also explain how to convert this value to RGB?